# SQLite hanging for 1 second on last row

Tags: c++, sqlite

When I execute this query using the cli, it's instant. When I execute this query and iterate over the results like so:

```
...
while (true) {
  if (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_DONE) {
    break;
  }
  ...
```

It hangs for 1 second on the last call to `sqlite3_step(stmt)`, why??

Running `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` I get the following output:

```
|--CO-ROUTINE first_event_per_day_calendar
|  |--CO-ROUTINE (subquery-4)
|  |  |--CO-ROUTINE filtered_and_numbered_events
|  |  |  |--CO-ROUTINE (subquery-5)
|  |  |  |  |--SCAN e
|  |  |  |  `--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
|  |  |  `--SCAN (subquery-5)
|  |  |--SCAN filtered_and_numbered_events
|  |  `--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
|  |--SCAN (subquery-4)
|  `--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
`--SCAN first_event_per_day_calendar
```

So playing with the query a little, I've managed to isolate what causes the query to be really slow.

```sql
WITH tmp AS (
  SELECT 
      e.id, 
      datetime(date(start_at / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'utc'), 'utc') AS start_of_day_timestamp
  FROM events e
  LIMIT 100
)
SELECT 
    e.id, 
    start_of_day_timestamp,
    -- Adding the below line causes the query to hang before returning SQLITE_DONE
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY start_of_day_timestamp ) AS row_num
FROM tmp e;
```

Comment: You could ask the debugger: simply step into that last call and see what it is doing. Or hit break in the debugger after half a second to see where your code ends up

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help much as I'm not compiling sqlite from source so it's just paused in some assembly. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: The amalgamated form of SQLite is just a single .c file that would allow you to compile with symbols and debug information, so I would give it a try.